# How to inject @Value into a bean using kotlin beans DSL

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I need to inject some config values into a bean, and I am trying to use the new dsl for kotlin. Basically, I need the java equivalent of the following, but for kotlin bean DSL

```java
public Thing myThing(@Value("${foo}") String foo) {
   return new Thing(foo)
}
```

in Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
val beans = beans {
    bean {
      Thing("????? How to get foo") // I need @Value("${foo}") here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `env`

```
import org.springframework.core.env.get

val beans = beans {
    bean {
      Thing(env["foo"]) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I don't see why you import `get`